# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This may be a very silly mistake but I just can't fix it. I have 2 tables, **Questions** and **Questions_Rating**.

**Questions**:

```
question_id    question            user_id
------------------------------------------
1              'How to blablabla'     1
2              'bla bla bla'          1
```

**Questions_Rating**

In this table, users will rate questions either by +1 or -1

```
question_rating_id   question_id     user_id      rate
------------------------------------------------------
1                         1            2          (+1)
2                         1            3          (+1)
3                         1            4          ( 1)
```

Now I would simply like to fetch the question from the `questions` table, and the SUM of the `rate` in the `questions_rating` table for this question, which has an `ID = 1`.

```
String QUERY = "SELECT q.question, SUM(r.rate) FROM questions q, questions_rating r WHERE  r.question_id = q.question_id AND q.question_id = 1";
```

And this is what I'm getting.

> *Column 'questions.question' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

I know that the `SUM` of the rate will return 1 row, and the question is supposedly 1 row, I can't figure out what's wrong with this query.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: you don't have the `GROUP BY question`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to Group the values as per the question so you need a

```
GROUP BY q.question
```

at the end of your query

[Good Explanation here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing [`group by`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause in your select statement.

 As you have used `sum()` function which is an `aggregate function` 
So you need to write `group by` for all the select columns.

```
  String QUERY = "SELECT 
                     q.question,
                     SUM(r.rate) 
                FROM 
                     questions q,
                     questions_rating r 
                where 
                     r.question_id = q.question_id AND 
                     q.question_id=1 
                group by 
                     q.question";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `group by q.question` in your SQL statement.

Your Sum is suppose to return only a single row against the table, since you are selecting a column along with  the Sum you need to specify a group on the selected column. In your case it should be `q.question`, and sum will be applied to each group of questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT q.question,SUM(r.rate) AS RateSum
FROM questions q,questions_rating r 
WHERE r.question_id = q.question_id AND q.question_id=1 
GROUP BY q.question
```

or (using ANSI 92 style joins)

```
SELECT q.question,SUM(r.rate) AS RateSum
FROM questions q INNER JOIN questions_rating r ON r.question_id = q.question_id
WHERE q.question_id=1 
GROUP BY q.question
```

or (using subqueries)

```
SELECT q.question, (SELECT SUM(r.rate) FROM questions_rating r WHERE r.question_id = q.question_id) AS RateSum
FROM questions q
WHERE q.question_id=1
```